# How can i create from two n-bit binary numbers a 2n-binary number?

Tags: java, binary

Lets suppose i have n=4 so two 4-bit binary numbers.`B1 = b1010` and `B2 = b0110`.
 I want to create an 8-bit number that looks like this `b10100110` (B1B2).
How can i do such a thing in Java?

Comment: Hint: `B1 * 0b1000 = 0b10100000`

Comment: Shift the higher-order byte left n places. Add the two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply one by `16`, which is the same as adding four zeroes to the end. Then add them. In general, multiplying by `2^n` adds `n zeroes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course multiply and add them as suggested.  I prefer using bit manipulation operators.

```
       int b1 = 0b1010;
       int b2 = 0b0110;

       // shift b1 left 4 bits and then OR it with b2.
       int result = (b1<<4)|b2;

       System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

As a side note, for every bit you shift left, you are multiplying by a power of 2. So shifting left by 4 bits is multiplying by 16.  For right shifting, you are dividing by powers of 2.